# Read asynchronously each line of an HTTP request

Tags: c#, http, asynchronous, stream

I use a strange API that sends JSON objects in kind of chunks (line by line).

I need to be able to read each line of the response to my request asynchronously. I'm already trying to display in the console each of these requests.

The code below is the main one (the `main{}` function only calls this function). I want this code to be executed asynchronously too, that's why the function is declared as `async task`.

When I launch the application, the query runs fine, but the program doesn't display the lines one by one: it waits for the end of the query to display everything at once.

I'm very new to async/streams, sorry if the code is so bad.

```cs
    public async Task test()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string> // POST data
            {
                { "api", "v2" },
                { "field1", "data1" },
                { "field2", "data2" }
            };
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
        var response = await client.PostAsync("http://api.domain/post", content);
        using (var theStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {
            StreamReader theStreamReader = new StreamReader(theStream);
            string theLine = null;
    
            while ((theLine = await theStreamReader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("----- New Line:"); //Just for the eyes
                Console.WriteLine(theLine);
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this should be working. You could try to specify waiting for head completion.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Thank you for your answer, how could I do ? an HTTP header or just a wait in the using()

Comment: HTTP does not work like that.  The entire response is returned in one chunk for 1.0.  HTTP has three modes 1) Standard HTTP (1.0) in stream mode 2) HTTP (1.1) in chunk mode 3) HTTP/2.  Switching to 1.1 or /2 will help.

Comment: @jdweng Thank you, the API server is using HTTP/1.1, and the default HTTP version of httpClient() is also 1.1, so I don't think that the issue is coming from this. After some debug, I found that the code wait for client.PostAsync() to end, and then execute the stream etc. Update: neither 1.1 nor 2.0 make the code work

Comment: The await is going to block until the entire HTTP response is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`, which will only block while reading the headers, and the content comes through asynchronously. You must use `SendAsync` and a `HttpRequestMessage` for this.

Also you are missing some `using` blocks, and `HttpClient` should be cached in a `static` field.

```cs
 static HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

 public async Task test()
 {
     var values = new Dictionary<string, string> // POST data
         {
             { "api", "v2" },
             { "field1", "data1" },
             { "field2", "data2" }
         };
     using (var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values))
     using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://api.domain/post"){ Content = content })
     using (var response = await _client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
     using (var theStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
     using (var theStreamReader = new StreamReader(theStream))
     {
         string theLine = null;
 
         while ((theLine = await theStreamReader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("----- New Line:"); //Just for the eyes
             Console.WriteLine(theLine);
         }
     };
 }
```